# How to output to a file request full HTTP request and response

Tags: curl

I've been using `fiddler` for a while and I can easily get full HTTP request and response for debugging purposes outputted to a file in the following format:

```
POST http://development.domain.com:8080/v1/tokens HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: development.domain.com:8080
Content-Length: 0
Authorization: Bearer DlpMs-AKiVJxEsM7TWrMPOuXvZk0F3dA

{"username": "some"}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 06:27:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

{"token":"cool"}
```

How can I achieve the following with curl? I've managed to get full response with `-i` option, however I'm struggling with getting full request. I've tried `-v`, but it outputs just too much information, whereas I only need request status text, headers and body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--trace-ascii logfile.txt` saves the entire request and response in the given file.

`--trace logfile.txt` saves the same, but in way that shows the binary values easier if the contents isn't only text

`--trace-time` adds timing information to each line in the above mentioned trace outputs.

Comment: thanks, is any way to remove redundant info like `<= Recv header, 47 bytes (0x2f)` or `=> Send header, 154 bytes (0x9a)`?

Comment: So no way to ouput information in the format I specified in my question?

Comment: No, not in that exact format. You'd need to reformat it with some additional script/command line tricks.

Comment: Ok, thanks, maybe you could provide some helpful code snippets?

Comment: this seems to do a good job: `curl --trace-ascii - http://domain.com:8080/v1/tokens | sed '/=>/d;/==/d;/<=/d' > httplog.txt`